# How to get entry backbutton press event in behaviors in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an entry for entering the mobile number, I want back button press event when erasing the entered mobile number in behaviours.

I have tried `OnBackButtonPressed()` in view code behind. But it is not fired when erasing the entry text. I have referred many sites but I didn't get any clear solution. Please give your valuable suggestion.

[image]

```
<Entry x:Name="phoneEntry" Placeholder="Phone Number" FontSize="14" PlaceholderColor="Gray" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Telephone">
      <Entry.Behaviors>  
          <behavior:EntryBehavior CommandParameter="{x:Reference phoneFormat}"/>                                                            
      </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

**PhoneNumber Format Behavior**

```
 public class EntryBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EntryBehavior));        

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged += Bindable_TextChanged;
    }

    private void Bindable_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (CommandParameter != null)
        {
            var index = (CommandParameter as MyList).SelectedIndex;

            if (index == 0 && ((Entry)sender).Text.Length < 14)
            {
                var value = args.NewTextValue;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.OldTextValue) && !args.NewTextValue.Contains("("))
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text = "(" + value;
                    return;
                }

                if (value.Length == 4)
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text += ") ";
                    return;
                }

                if (value.Length == 9)
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text += "-";
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (index == 1 && ((Entry)sender).Text.Length < 14)
            {
                var value = args.NewTextValue;
                if (((Entry)sender).Text.Length == 1 && !((Entry)sender).Text.Contains("("))
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text += "(";
                    return;
                }

                if (value.Length == 5)
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text += ") ";
                    return;
                }

                if (value.Length == 7 && !((Entry)sender).Text.Contains(" ") && !((Entry)sender).Text.Contains(")"))
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text += " ";
                    return;
                }

                if (value.Length == 10)
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text += "-";
                    return;
                }
            }

            ((Entry)sender).Text = args.NewTextValue;
        }
    }       

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

**I want to format the phone number based on type**

**Type1** : (xxx) xxx-xxxx

**Type2** : x(xxx) xxx-xxxx

Comment: @SushiHangover, No, Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: You need to handle Entry.TextChanged event

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi, By using TextChanged event how can i find, the phone number is now erasing or not.

Comment: You can count the string if it is deleted or not.

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi, There is any other better solution instead of counting the string length?

Comment: Not there is not that is the only solution

Comment: Refer this link similar example to your type 1 format: https://xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1):

**First solution** 
Assuming you use bindings 
`<Entry Text="{Binding EntryText}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>`
in your ViewModel change EntryText implementation to

```
private string entryText;
public string EntryText
{
    get => entryText;
    set
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryText) && value.Length < entryText.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Char was deleted");
        }

        SetProperty(ref entryText, value);
    }
}
```

**Second solution**
You don't use MVVM pattern and you do everything in code behind.Change you entry line to 
`<Entry Grid.Row="2" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>`

Now, create a `Handle_TextChanged` implementation:

```
public void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is Entry label))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue) && e.NewTextValue.Length < e.OldTextValue.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Char deleted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the if statemt to Lenght == 0, then this is the correct answer

Comment: @DennisSchröer, I am not sure where do you want to put that. Can you please edit my answer so I can see it?

Comment: @lawiluk, In my situation i have formatting the phone number. But your suggestion is not working for me. Please see my updated code.

Comment: @Yogeshwaran sorry mate but your question is still not precise. You asked for a solution for removing a character from your entry. You got it. Either fully change your question or create a new one. You don't need to detect char removed event. You wan't to format the phone number and handle it properly

Comment: @lawiluk, Please help with my updated code. Phone number formatting is my scenario. I have updated the xaml also please refer. I have struggle to make the phone number for formatting.